# Reposition a absolute positioned image using jQuery

Tags: jquery, image, html

I have a relative positioned div to display the profile icon and the image will be displayed in this div.Image is absolute positioned.Top and left determines which part should be displayed.The display works perfectly but the problem is the top and left doesnt change when using ajax after editing the icon.Editing includes increasing size, changing background etc. There is a option to edit icon where the user can select what part to display, after editing icon i had stored the width,height,background,top,left in database which will be the attributes to the icon. By using ajax i retrieved data from database and changed width,height,background,top,left. But only width,height and background is only changing. It will only change if reload because i used php to set the attributes when page loads. Hope you understand!

My jquery code:

```
if(type=="picon")
        {
            $.post("changedDB.php", type, function(data, status){ 
            var spicture=data.split("|");
            $(".profile-picture").attr("src", spicture[0]);
            $(".profile-picture").css({"position":"absolute","width":""+spicture[1],"height":""+spicture[2],"background":""+spicture[3],"top":""+spicture[5],"left":""+spicture[6]});
            });
        }
```

**Data from server**

```
The value in data is "image url|70|50|rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)|0|-10|-5"
The format corresponds to "image url|width|height|background|show full image|top|left
```

But the top and left remains unchanged it is having the value i had set using php when the page loads.

How can i change the top and left using jquery?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show what is the data that server is responding?

Comment: Why not return a JSON object from your PHP, and save yourself the `data.split("|");`? Also, `""+spicture[5]` it is unnecessary to append that value to an empty string.

Comment: @harikrishnan.n0077 See my response below and tell me if it worked

Comment: @crush only way to retrieve updated value from server side is using ajax withou loading

Comment: @harikrishnan.n0077 What does that have to do with having it return JSON as opposed to a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you didn't specify the units. Concat your dimensions with "px"

Change your code to this:

```
$(".profile-picture").css({"position":"absolute","width":""+spicture[1] + "px","height":""+spicture[2] + "px","background":""+spicture[3],"top":""+spicture[5] + "px","left":""+spicture[6] + "px"});
```

Comment: Or he could use `offset()`. Also, I think jQuery will add the units for you, if you leave them off in `css()`.

Comment: px will be automatically added to style

Comment: Using JSON responses it would be easier to debug. Also you would not need to split text. Can you give a link to the page in question?